# flask app not running - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So when i try to run my flask app with : python3 app.py (in the virtual environment), i get the error below.
the database is running fine, my email is configured for my mail sender, all necessary libraries are installed, i checked everything and it seems fine.

```
(venv) abderrahim@rahimint:~/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API$ python3 authanthification_main.py 
authanthification_main.py:29: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
 * Serving Flask app "authanthification_main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "authanthification_main.py", line 228, in <module>
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=100)
  File "/home/abderrahim/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/abderrahim/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/abderrahim/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/home/abderrahim/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 848, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/home/abderrahim/Documents/PFE/CodeSource/API/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Looking at it, I'm getting the impression that you are trying to run the application on a port which requires additional privileges. Say port 80 or 443? Am I correct here?

Comment: Looking at the code, the OP is attempting to bind to port `100` (`app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=100)`), which on most systems will not be possible without elevated (`root`) privileges.

Comment: Well i chaged the port to 5000 and it works, thank you for that.